# Why is Queue/FIFO ordering important in Message Queue?

Tags: data-structures, design-patterns, message-queue, system-design

One option for a *Messaging Provider* is a *[Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)*, which provides FIFO ordering, i.e. Queue. Why would the ordering of messages be important? I wonder if is it because of the priority of the messages or anything similar to that. i would appreciate if anyone could explain with example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is right - logically some operations are interdependent and you must maintain the order of calls.

But I think that there is an even more important purely technical aspect to this that I want to point out: You need to know the order to be able to achieve ACID transactions.

Take the following scenario:

You have a process service that orchestrates 5 other entity/utility services. The process gets triggered and starts executing but 3rd call fails. More often than not it is too expensive to have a common transactional context between services (in order to have 2-phase commit), so the solution is to use *Compensation* i.e. to call the opposite operations of all services that already did a write operation before the failure. If you cannot guarantee the order of the messages, you cannot possibly know what you should rollback and what not (if you don't explicitly look in the underlying systems and track the change yourself - but this is not a sane approach).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying. This make it more clear now. Thanks for the help buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I wrote for my answer:

By implementing a Queue data structure, Consumers will receive messages in order by which they were sent. For example, An Order System in Enterprise systems sends some messages to Sales System. Let these be "GetPayment" and "Make a Shipment". If these messages are not queued, the Sales System could malfunction by notifying to "Make a Shipment" before "Getting a Payment".

The idea is to maintain the enterprise level workflow.

**PS**: Plamen has more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsoever gets into the message buffer first should be served first. Message queues are used to retain the order of the messages received. Queues are First in and first out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was looking for an enterprise systems point of view answer rather than technical. Thank you again.